# Is it safe to shave a Chow-Chow for the summer?

Tags: dogs, grooming

We own a 6-month old Chow-Chow. We'd like to take him to a professional groomer now that summer is here. Are there any special precautions we should pay attention to? I've heard that some dogs have a two-layer coat and that it can be dangerous to shave both layers, is this true?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Double coated dogs (such as the Chow Chow and many others) should never be shaved unless it's for medical reasons such as a skin disease or other vet recommended procedure. A dog's double coat actually helps insulate a dog to keep him cool in the summer and warm in the winter.

Shaving a double coated dog will not only prevent a dog from keeping cool, it can actually make them overheat and more likely to get sunburn. Besides that, the fur rarely grows in the same and you end up with fur that doesn't look right and is not as soft as it was previously. Here is a diagram explaining the purpose of the double coat.

[image: Double Coated Dog Airflow]

The best way to groom a dog with a double coat is to use a combination of an [undercoat rake](http://smile.amazon.com/dp/B007N3C7TY/) and [wire comb](http://smile.amazon.com/dp/B004UTDHP2/). For our dog, Nova (an American Eskimo), the wire comb is usually good enough, but the undercoat rake can come in handy to get rid of any mats or extra dense spots. Grooming regularly (we groom Nova about once a week) makes the job very easy and only takes a little while. It also helps keep the dog cool in the summer and prevents mats from building up that prevent airflow.

Comment: On the other side my GF's chow chow had some coat issue over the neck because of the collar, and it summer in Paris can be quite hot, her flat also do not help, so in that case, she did a medium hair cut all around the body except the head, and actually the chow chow was so happy and jumping every where... Please note that 1. it helps to get an homogene cot, like a "reset", and the coat growth really fast. No, my GF's chow chow is not mistreated at all, he gets every day care and coat dressing, but yeah, if you do a medium coat cut + a shampoo sometimes, the dog will not complaign.