# Should I cut my Pomeranian's fur for summer?

Tags: dogs, grooming

Should you get a Pomeranian's fur cut real short for the summer?
We had our dog's fur cut real short and I've noticed this summer that
She is panting a lot!! And harder!!

Comment: Related [Can furry pets get sunburn?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5824/can-furry-pets-get-sunburn/5825#5825)

Comment: You might get better results with more detail on how short is "real short". What number (on the clippers) was used? Or you can edit your post with a photo.

Comment: Potential duplicate to https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/5612/1277. Both Pomeranians and Chow-Chow are double-coated dogs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would definitely help! There are also a few other ways to keep her cool in the summer.

1) Keep your house cool by closing the blinds/curtains and keeping windows closed. Depending where you are opening the windows first thing in the morning helps as you get a cool breeze but as the day passes and it gets hotter it's best to shut them.

2) Putting the dogs things (bed, food, water, toys) in the basement helps on hot days, the dog can spend the majority of the time there.

3) Keep walks to the morning or late afternoon when it's cooler.

4) Buy a small kids pool and fill it with water for your dog to have a nice swim or to lay in.

5) There are dog beds made to help keep pets cool, they are typically elevated. [Pet cooling cot](https://www.wayfair.ca/Go-Pet-Club-Elevated-Cooling-Cot-Pet-Bed-GPC1312-L915-K~GPC1312.html?refid=GX185223812606-GPC1312&device=c&ptid=152635249500&targetid=pla-152635249500) is an example.

6) Frozen dog treats help, [here are some ideas](https://www.rover.com/blog/homemade-dog-treats-freezer-summer/) (disclamer: make sure peanut butter is xylitol free).

7) Keep the air conditioning on at home.